# Value of variable outside $.get call not been set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the value of a variable from inside a $.get jquery call but it is not working. Below is my code

```
var uData = [];
$('#tfriends').click(function () {
    get_json(function () {                     
       alert(uData);
    });
});


function get_json(callback) {
    $.get('url', function (data) {
        var data = $.map(data.result, function (obj) {
            obj.Id = obj.Id || obj.name;
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
            return obj;
        }, "json");
        uData = data;
    });
 }
```

Comment: You need to call your callback (and pass a parameter)

Comment: 1) You have a syntax error - an additional `'` which you can see is messing up the syntax highlighting 2) You don't actually call `callback` anywhere. Add `callback()` after setting `uData`

Comment: Please can you provide an example code, am quite a novice in JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: `"json"` should be passed to `$.get`, not `$.map`.

Comment: @baao no, it's not a duplicate of that answer - the OP had is mostly right _except_ for not calling the callback

Comment: @Alnitak I agree that it's not an exact duplicate, but the answer explains how callbacks (and async in general) work. By reading and understanding the answer, OP will get a true understanding of what's going on, and I suppose they could have solved the problem theirself.

Comment: @felix the reason for the map is because I want to use the returned data in a select2 dropbox

Comment: @OghaleEtomu: I'm not saying that you shouldn't use map. I'm saying that [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) only accepts two arguments. The third argument, `"json"` is ignored and if any it has to be passed to [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: @OghaleEtomu actually you're kind of abusing the `.map`, because ultimately you're just modifying the elements in place within the `.map` callback, with the newly created `data` array just being a copy of the (now-modified) `data.result` array.  It would be easier to use `.forEach` and return `data.result` directly (per my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your callback function inside the `$.get` function. Check the comment below.

```
var uData = [];
$('#tfriends').click(function () {
    get_json(function () {                     
       alert(uData);
    });
});


function get_json(callback) {
    $.get('url', function (data) {
        var data = $.map(data.result, function (obj) {
            obj.Id = obj.Id || obj.name;
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
            return obj;
        }, "json");
        uData = data;
        callback() // this line will actually call your callback function
    });
 }
```

**Edit**
As @FelixKling suggested below, you can pass the data in the callback itself rather than declaring a global variable as so

```
// var uData = [];
$('#tfriends').click(function () {
    get_json(function (returned_data) {                     
       alert(returned_data);
    });
});


function get_json(callback) {
    $.get('url', function (data) {
        var data = $.map(data.result, function (obj) {
            obj.Id = obj.Id || obj.name;
            obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
            return obj;
        }, "json");
        //uData = data;
        callback(data) // this line will actually call your callback function
    });
 }
```

Comment: Better yet: pass `data` to `callback`. There is no need for a global variable.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks. updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now

Answer (score 1):

This would (IMHO) be better with Promises, abstracting the *retrieval of the resource*, from the *pre-processing*, and then from the subsequent *application layer handling*:

```
// resource retrieval
function get_json() {
    return $.get('url');
}

// pre processing
function preprocess(data) {
    // no need to use `.map` since you're modifying the data in-place
    data.result.forEach(function(obj) {
        obj.Id = obj.Id || obj.name;
        obj.text = obj.text || obj.name;
    });

    return data.result;
}

// chaining it all together
get_json().then(preprocess).then(callback);
```

If the pre-process stage is *always* required then it would be acceptable to incorporate that in `get_json`:

```
function get_json() {
    return $.get('url').then(preprocess);
}
```